# Group by and sort Dataframe then subsequently find first occurrence based on criteria

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following DataFrame, and I'm trying to find for each customer, when the first date (in ascending order) does the flag column = Y

```
df = {
  "customer_key": ["1","1","1","2","2","2"],
  "date": ["2020-09-30", "2020-01-31", "2020-06-30","2020-01-31", "2020-02-29", "2020-03-31"],
  "flag": ["Y","N","Y","N","N","Y"]
}
```

Results expected:

- For customer 1 it would be 2020-06-30.
- For customer 2 it would be 2020-03-31.

So first I'm sorting by the date.

```
df.sort_values('date', inplace=True)
```

Here is where I get stuck, I know I need to group by customer key and then find the first occurrence where the flag = y, I'm just now sure how to do this pythonicly.

```
df['first_occurence_date'] = df.groupby(by='customer_key') ## i dunno...
```

Comment: `df["flag"].eq("Y").groupby(df["customer_key"]).idxmax()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
out = df.loc[df['flag'].eq('Y')].groupby('customer_key').date.min()
customer_key
1    2020-06-30
2    2020-03-31
Name: date, dtype: object
```

Comment: this worked, but when i tried to do: ```df['first_date'] = df.loc[df['flag'].eq('Y')].groupby('customer_key').date.min()``` I got all nan(s).

Comment: @mikelowry df['first_date'] = out .reindex(df.customer_key).values